# Where can i configure themes?! and how?!

Tags: themes

I am using Adwaita theme and I love it but I just wanted to do some changes in some colors highlights and graphics. yes I can install compizconfig and other software, but I want to understand a little  bit about the files management and things like that.

So what I want in particular is where are the files(directories) in which I can configure the themes?

Second where can I find more technical and programming Information about the themes and things related.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the files in `/usr/share/themes/THEME_NAME/gtk-*` directories. As for example, open `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` file in your terminal:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

*(or other text editors of your choice.)*

make the changes; say change the colour theme from:

```
gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#000000\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000\nselected_bg_color:#86ABD9\nselected_fg_color:#ffffff\ntext_color:#1A1A1A\nbg_color:#EDECEB\ntooltip_bg_color:#E7F3FD"
```

to

```
gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#000000\ntooltip_fg_color:#00ff00\nselected_bg_color:#ff0000\nselected_fg_color:#0000ff\ntext_color:#1A1A1A\nbg_color:#EDECEB\ntooltip_bg_color:#00ff00"
```

*(here I've made changes to the values of tooltip_fg_color, selected_bg_color, selected_fg_color and tooltip_bg_color)*

(To save, in `nano` enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit.)

Change and reapply the theme you've made changes to and see them in effect.